# Find and replace/wrap certain terms in html tags

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to replace certain text in a html string with a html anchor tag surrounding that text, I've tried using REPLACE to simply find and replace the term but then it ends up finding matches inside words and html attributes which I don't want. The closest I've got to it actually working is using [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) and [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) shown in the example below however it only replaces the first occurrence and it replaces the boundary characters (i.e. the [ ,.] chars) as well as the actual term.

## Example

```
DECLARE @start TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @end TABLE (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @start 
VALUES ('change me plz'),('change me and me plz too'),('dont change this meme'),('nope'),('<a title="don''t click me ever">not me</a> and change me')

DECLARE @searchTerm VARCHAR(50) = 'me';
DECLARE @replaceTerm VARCHAR(50) = '<a href="about:blank">me</a>';
DECLARE @pattern VARCHAR(50) = '%[ ,.]' + @searchTerm + '[ ,.]%';
DECLARE @currentVal VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @currentId INT = (
    SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @start WHERE val like @pattern
);

SELECT * FROM @start

WHILE(@currentId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
PRINT @currentId;
    SELECT @currentVal = STUFF(val, PATINDEX(@pattern, val), LEN(@searchTerm)+2, @replaceTerm)
    FROM @start
    WHERE id = @currentId

    INSERT INTO @end (id, val)
    VALUES (@currentId, @currentVal)

    DELETE FROM @start
    WHERE
    id = @currentId

    SET @currentId = (
        SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @start WHERE val like @pattern
    );
END

SELECT * FROM @end
```

## tl;dr;

how do you add html tags around text in a html string so that the html is still valid and you only replace the whole word/term not substrings of other words

Comment: Based on your comment on Scott's answer, can you please update your question to include some representative sample data. thanks.

Comment: @srutzky example added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is not the best with String Manipulation.  If this functionality will change over time or become complex in any nature, I would suggest you look into CLR as a way to search/replace complex strings.  [Here's a great article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) from Phil Factor on Simple Talk that walks through how to use CLR for complex string operations.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yeah i figured it might be the only way around it I've used the CLR before to create hashes directly in sql but wasn't sure how performance would be doing regex over a large number of records (the like patterns were pretty bad as is).

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this will do what you want.

```
DECLARE @start TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,val VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @start
VALUES ('change me plz')
    ,('change me and me plz too')
    ,('dont change this meme')
    ,('nope')
    ,('me at the beginning')
    ,('string ending in me')

--Add a space to the beginning and ending of the string to handle
--the searchterm being at the beginning and/or ending.  Then replace
--looking for ' ' + SearchTerm + ' '
--Remove the beginning and ending space before actually updating the value
UPDATE @start
SET val = Ltrim(Rtrim(replace(' ' + val + ' ', ' me ', '<a href="about:blank">me</a>')))

SELECT *
FROM @start
```

Resulting in:

```
| id | val                                                                      |
|----|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | change<a href="about:blank">me</a>plz                                    |
| 2  | change<a href="about:blank">me</a>and<a href="about:blank">me</a>plz too |
| 3  | dont change this meme                                                    |
| 4  | nope                                                                     |
| 5  | <a href="about:blank">me</a>at the beginning                             |
| 6  | string ending in<a href="about:blank">me</a>                             |
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this would fix the substring issue i was having when using replace and think is the closest i'm going to get to a purely sql solution but it can't deal with the combination of different boundary characters and i forgot to add it to my example inputs but it would produce invalid html if the term occurred in a html attribute (my example above does too actually)